# Is it possible to restore a WhatsApp backup package?

Tags: email, backup, android, whatsapp, text

I wrote a post after hearing how long I have to wait for the WA backup. a high member, talk to me, i should all write in english, not in german pls. I think ok, I'm a new member, I'm doing this.

then i delete my post, but I dont know, that the Highmember put my Whatsapp backup in that post. we also come back to my question.

Is it possible to restore my backup file or are these delete directly by the server? i hope the files can download again, but it is very important for me.
i hope you can send me this file again.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pls tell me, what is the Problem, that you cant sent the WhatsApps Backup to me again?

Regards.